# Windows 10 multi-booting same OS (services/boot)

Tags: windows-10, boot, multi-boot

I'm dual booting (multi-booting) my ASUS GL502VMK laptop. (both drives [C: & F:] are running Windows 10)

My C: is for work and personal stuff; while F: is for gaming and random stuff.

Apart from a guide if there's any on how to actually run what I'm doing correctly, I would like to know about some software services I'm running on different drive partitions.

For instance, on my C: I wouldn't have Razer Synapse because I'm not planning to game on there, however, on my F: on surely going for Razer Synapse, this software's services are preset to start on boot. Meaning if I ever turn on my machine for my personal stuff (The C: where I don't game) the service on F: would still send the signal to run this software right?

So basically my question is if I'm multi-booting do I need to configure each programm's service to boot on user login instead of boot?

Comment: _Meaning if I ever turn on my machine for my personal stuff (The C: where I don't game) the service on F: would still send the signal to run this software right?_ - No. The software simply residing on the F: drive does not mean it will start when you bootup your personal stuff system; unless you explicitly set it to do so. If you're dual booting two Windows 10 systems they will act as two completely separate OS's and the services you setup on one will not automatically be setup on the other.

Answer (score 0):

No. No matter in what partition they are, if they are configured to start automatically after boot, then they'll do so. Usually those are programs that are configured by default after install to start up automatically after boot, but you can configure auto startup software as well.

When (for example) Windows boots, there is an *auto startup service* that has been configured to start other programs after boot.

To see how to configure such software to automatically start on boot or remove it, see [Microsoft's article: Change which apps run automatically at startup in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026268/windows-10-change-startup-apps).